# SSRS report 2005 in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report

We are using SQL Server 2005 DB and front end code (ASP.net) in VS2010.

When i designed the report in 2005 and run the code it pop-up the error saying
 " Remote report processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or later. "

We can't change the SQL Server from 2005 to 2008 :(

How can we overcome this situation ?

Any Idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed vs 2005 or .net framework 2.0 then just add report viewer in vs2010 and change its version from 10.0.0.0 to 8.0.0.0. Version changes occurred **in  design page** and  **in web .config** then you are able to see the report in vs 2010